# How to daemonize c application in windows

Tags: c, windows, daemon

Lets say i have c application code.

when i give argument -d with executable. E.g. application.exe -d it should run in the background.

I achieved this on unix using fork()
but i am not able to achieve this on windows.

i have used this code in code, but it is not running in background

```
    printf("We are in daemon mode");
    STARTUPINFO startInfo;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION process;

    ZeroMemory(&startInfo, sizeof(startInfo));
    ZeroMemory(&process, sizeof(process));

    startInfo.cb = sizeof(startInfo);
char* command = "application.exe";
    // Tell the system to use/honor the ShowWindow flags.
    startInfo.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
    // Tell the system that the main window of the process should be hidden.
    startInfo.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE;
    if (!CreateProcessA(
            command,            // application name
            NULL,            // command line arguments
            NULL,                // process attributes
            NULL,                // thread attributes
            FALSE,                // inherit (file) handles
            // Detach the process from the current console.
            DETACHED_PROCESS,   // creation flags
          // CREATE_NO_WINDOW,
            NULL,                // environment
            NULL,                // current directory
            &startInfo,            // startup info
            &process)            // process information
        ) {

        printf("Creation of the process failed, trying to fetch error message...\n");

        long lastError = GetLastError();
        char* message = NULL;

        FormatMessageA(
            FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER |
            FORMAT_MESSAGE_ARGUMENT_ARRAY |
            FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM |
            FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS, // Flags
            NULL,               // source
            lastError,          // message identifier
            0,                  // language id
            (LPSTR)&message,   // message buffer
            0,                  // size of the message
            NULL                // arguments
        );

        printf(message);

        return 1;
    }
```

Comment: Try with [`CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP` flag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/process-creation-flags).